# polyglossia's \setotherlanguage blocks imakeindex's \indexprologue

Tags: polyglossia, imakeidx

In the MWE below (now there is one!) `\indexprologue` gives no output. It does if I comment out the language setting for Arabic. What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}


\setotherlanguage{arabic} % Comment this and the indexprologue appears


\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\index{entry}

\indexprologue{\kant[1]}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but a basic test works. A MWE is definitely needed.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to say is preciesly that it works. I havn't been able to replicate the conditions under which it does't. I have a preamble of 1400 rows and didnt want to paste it all here.

Comment: Take a look at [this guide to MWE creation](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It is (almost) always possible to create an MWE simply by repeated code removal, compilation and code reinstatement. This can take a while in a large document if you have no idea what the problem is - in that case, 2 hours is not much. You just have to keep at it. However, a preamble of 1400 rows sounds ridiculous. I would more-or-less expect to have problems in that case unless some of that code should better be a personal `.sty` file.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, that's a helpful link. I'll go at it again.

Comment: It's `bidi` that restores the standard definition of `theindex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem with `bidi` that seizes the initiative and, for no apparent reason, restores the `book` definition of the `theindex` environment.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

% nullify bidi redefinition
% this should go after polyglossia and imakeidx have been loaded
\let\imakeidxtheindex\theindex
\let\imakeidxendtheindex\endtheindex
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\theindex\imakeidxtheindex
  \let\endtheindex\imakeidxendtheindex
}

\makeindex

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic} % Comment this and the indexprologue appears

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\index{entry}

\indexprologue{\kant[1]}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this something that should be fixed in bidi?

Comment: @Andreas I think so.